# Tensorflow - Saved_model_cli.py - (ModuleNotFoundError when compiling with Code Runner in VSCode)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, visual-studio-code, tensorflow-serving

I am somewhat new to this space - hoping that the answer to this question is simple for someone more experienced (I am little bit stumped).

I am building a simple RNN machine Learning model using LSTM and saving the model as a Tensorflow serving. I am saving in this format using the keras API. Now trying to inspect the saved model using the 'saved_model_cli.py'. I am using VSCode to build the model - the issue is that when I run this on the terminal (within VSCode), it processes fine and without error but when running this with code runner (via the output window), I get a modulenotfound error? The module specified is found in the 'lib' folder (within a venv folder). Is there a reason as to why it is behaving this way - appreciate the support.

**Code Sample**

```
tf.keras.models.save_model(
    model,
    export_path,
    overwrite=True,
    include_optimizer=True,
    save_format=None,
    signatures=None,
    options=None,
)

print("\nSaved Model Contents:")
with open("saved_model_contents.txt", "w") as f:
    p1 = subprocess.run(["ls", "-al", export_path], stdout=f, text=True)

p2 = subprocess.run(["ls", export_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, check=True)
print(p2.stdout)

with open("saved_model_inspect.txt", "w") as g:
    p3 = subprocess.run(
        "python3 /Users/lisatsakalian/Desktop/Coding_Projects/ML_Projects_Dev/NLP/project_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/saved_model_cli.py  show --dir /var/folders/5y/s74tfz4n3nndnj8gdd2_jdmw0000gn/T/1 --all",
        shell=True,
        stdout=g,
        text=True,
    )
```

Comment: Could you please specify the versions you are using for tensorflow and tensorflow serving?Also please provide more detail about the error trace to help us debug better.

Comment: Thanks for the support.

Tensorflow: 2.5.0
Tensorflow-serving-api: 2.5.1

![Screen Shot 2021-05-23 at 10 52 29 AM](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/81199296/119266216-dd3b6a80-bbb7-11eb-904c-c34f3e1a5d33.png)

One again, I am just getting familiar with this space - if you could direct me to which/where to grab logs would provide - here is what I found:

![Screen Shot 2021-05-23 at 11 17 23 AM](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/81199296/119266365-84200680-bbb8-11eb-98e9-f727c4373b8f.png)

Comment: This is just a guess. Thinking this may be because I am using the 'Shell' command and may not be intended to run in the output window in VScode. Because it does work when compiling in the terminal.

Comment: By running in the output window, Do you mean running the `saved_model_cli` as a part of your existing Python script? Is yes, then what you said is true because it is command to run in terminal.